# C# Events and execution on thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have a method that subscribes to a event (from a SDK). If that event fires, the method always runs into the "Invoke needed" expression. Does that mean, that the event executes on another thread? How do events generally do this? I am a newbie with events, so please explain. Thanks a lot!

```
void TrackingOnNewTrackingObservations(object sender, TrackingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!dgvTracking.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dgvTracking.Rows[0].Cells["cName"].Value = "SlopeDistance";
                dgvTracking.Rows[0].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00} m", e.SlopeDistance);

                dgvTracking.Rows[1].Cells["cName"].Value = "HorizontalAngle";
                dgvTracking.Rows[1].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00000}°", e.HorizontalAngle);

                dgvTracking.Rows[2].Cells["cName"].Value = "VerticalAngle";
                dgvTracking.Rows[2].Cells["cValue"].Value = string.Format("{0:0.00000}°", e.VerticalAngle);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Invoke needed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error TrackingOnNewTrackingObservations ->" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Events are executed on the thread that invokes them. If you are creating the events and handlers, you would have control over which threads they are executed on. In this case, you are handling an event from an SDK, I would say that you could not guarantee that your handler will be run from the same thread that you think you are executing. The SDK may be creating a new thread which invokes the event.

Comment: @Mikanikal but from the analysing, the InvokeRequired is always on true. So that means that the SDK is actually using a new thread to invoke the event, right?

Comment: yes. If the InvokeRequired is true, it is telling you it has to be invoked. It is an assumption right now that the SDK is generating it's own thread and that the event gets fired on that thread. You could debug this or log this and determine if the thread the event gets fired on is the same thread as your initial thread. They would have separate thread Ids. You should be able to check that with some debugging/logging and using the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`

Comment: @Mikanikal alright. So what I did was, I put `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` into the constructor of one of the UI classes. The Thread ID returned `8`. I also put that line into the method that gets fired by the event and the Thread ID was `9`. So I assume now, it actually creates a new thread, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, those are different thread IDs so it is a clear indicator that the thread executing the event (from the SDK) is not your initial thread. An invoke will be required.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help @Mikanikal